# Vault HA with Raft as storage backed - auto join

Tags: hashicorp-vault, raft

At the time of writing this, the latest Vault version is 1.3. This supports the joining of a node to a Raft cluster.

I've seen that in the official example the join seems that must be run manually. So the first node run `vault operator init` and all the others join.

Is there currently a way to have the Raft join mechanism automatic out-of-the-box? I believe not so this must be handled externally with some tooling. is it right?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://github.com/banzaicloud/bank-vaults

Comment: Yeah i knew it but i did not know that they handled Raft auto join. niceee https://github.com/banzaicloud/bank-vaults/blob/fdb9cceb5b8e1f88d7d11c4a60a5e5c92edfefe6/pkg/sdk/vault/operator_client.go found. thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can find an example in Hashicorp Learn

raft `retry_join` can do auto-join.

https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/kubernetes-raft-deployment-guide?in=vault%2Fkubernetes#configure-vault-helm-chart